# renew objects more than one time

Tags: c#, java

We can create two objects with just one name like this:
(my question is about **param** object)

```
List<ParameterClass> parameters = new ArrayList<ParameterClass>();
ParameterClass param = new ParameterClass();
param.setName("name1");
parameters.add(param);

param = new ParameterClass();
param.setName("name2");
parameters.add(param);
```

As you see this code compiles and works nicely. But my question is whether you recommend this kind of coding? using one variable for different goals is acceptable? why should we not do it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is acceptable if this is all of your code that uses this variable

When you declare and initialize the first one, the compiler write code to reserve an area of memory for the instance pointed by the param variable, you use that variable to set properties,

```
ParameterClass param = new ParameterClass();
param.setName("name1");
parameters.add(param);
```

then you declare and initialize another area of memory and use the same variable to point to this area, but it is a completely different area and there is no way to mix the two

```
param = new ParameterClass();
param.setName("name2");
parameters.add(param);
```

Of course you need to pass the reference to these area to some container object to be able to retrieve them later

Answer (score 2):

Reusing variables is acceptable but it does hamper code readability and can also lead to hard to locate bugs. You need to weigh accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like:

```
List<ParameterClass> parameters = new ArrayList<ParameterClass>();
parameters.add(new ParameterClass("name1"));
parameters.add(new ParameterClass("name2"));
```

This would remove your parameter variable, and solve your problem.

You need to have a constructor that takes name as an argument of course, but I think it is a fair game.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see nothing wrong with parametr reuse. Of course, readibility of code is another thing.

Comment: Why should the first instance vanish? It was already put in the list, so the list still holds a reference.

Comment: Because first instance is only pointer and you rewrite memory where it points to.

Comment: There is a second "new ParameterClass" operation. So after that param points to another memory location, but the list still holds the reference to the old one. The first one is not lost. That's from Java's perspective, I do not know c#. Just run the program from the question, iterate over the list, and print the elements: There are two elements with different memory locations.

Answer (score 1):

In this code

```
ParameterClass param = new ParameterClass();
```

param is just a reference to the object created by new(). When you call new() again the reference will point to the newly created object. So you can say reference is kind of dummy here since you intention is to populate ArrayList.

In a sense this in fact is the **right approach**. When you say `parameters.add(param);` **what actually happens is another reference is created and is pointed to your old object. Now you are free to direct your old reference to any new objects that you create.**

Answer (score 1):

Either go the way Mingyu described (= not to use a name at all), another possibility is to narrow the scope of the name:

```
List<ParameterClass> parameters = new ArrayList<ParameterClass>();

{
  ParameterClass param = new ParameterClass();
  param.setName("name1");
  parameters.add(param);
}

{
  ParameterClass param = new ParameterClass();
  param.setName("name2");
  parameters.add(param);
}
```

This way you can "reuse" the name, and it ensures that param is not used in a buggy way further down the road.

This is also "copy & paste safe", because errors like this can be hard to spot:

```
ParameterClass param = new ParameterClass();
List<ParameterClass> parameters = new ArrayList<ParameterClass>();
param.setName("name1");
parameters.add(param);

param.setName("name2");
parameters.add(param);
```